# cron job not retrieving web page content?

Tags: php, cron, cron-task

I am trying to use a cron job to preform daily calculation using url (GET 'https://www.t......com/bonus/go') and with the result link to my email.

But I get this result in my email:

```
</head>
<body>
  <div id="sf-resetcontent" class="sf-reset">
  <h1>Sorry, the page you are looking for could not be found
  </h1>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: does the page load in a web browser?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Other users marked your question for low quality and need for improvement. I re-worded/formatted your input to make it easier to read/understand. Please review my changes to ensure they reflect your intentions. But I think your question is still not answerable. **You** should [edit] your question now, to add missing details (see [mcve] ). Feel free to drop me a comment in case you have further questions or feedback for me.

Comment: Is it relevant that this is performed by a cron job? If not, remove every reference to cron from your question.

Answer (score 0):

This mean that the URL that you are pointing is not valid, doesn't exists or is not reachable from the context where the cron is running.

Please check if the URL is displayed on the web browser. If you haven't a web browser where the cron is running check with curl in command line:

```
$ curl -L {your-url}
```

- The **-L** is to allow curl to follow redirects.

Comment: Thanks for your respond, however when i try the url on some browser its work while on other fail browser its fail with error massage (Sorry, the page you are looking for could not be found.)    ------ https://www.takerss.com/bonus/go

Comment: I also tried your command line but got error massage --- /bin/bash: $: command not found

Comment: This should be a comment not an answer. Yes, you are giving a hint, but the problem is: the question can't be answered. We have no idea what exactly he is doing. You are giving some *debugging* hints, but you are not answering the question here!